# How can I convert an ATS file to SFMOV file?

Tags: video, file-conversion, flir

I have captured raw videos in .ats format via a FLIR SC8000 camera using ResearchIR software. I need to convert them to .sfmov format. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ResearchIR` software, click on `file`, then click on `export` and then select the following options:

```
Export type: multiple images
Export format: SAF image
```

[image]